# I need to draw a dotted line to divide a page, ignoring the margin

Tags: margins, rules

I can draw a rule across the entire pagewidth with the following command:

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt}}
```

but I can't draw a dotted line. Any ideas? I need the line to divide the page, ignoring the margin, that is, drawing the dotted line even in the margin area.

Answer (score 2):

Insert a `\dotfill`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\dividepage}{%
  \par\noindent
  \makebox[\linewidth]{\raisebox{.2\baselineskip}{\makebox[2\paperwidth]{\dotfill}}}%
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\dividepage

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I've raised it slightly to set it in the middle between two paragraphs. For overkill, I've specified `2\paperwidth` as the width of the `\dotfill` as to ensure it will stretch into both margins (and off the page).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tikz solution :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcounter{SplCounter}

\def\tikzmark#1{\tikz[remember picture]\coordinate(#1);}

\newlength{\yplace}
\newcommand\mySplitter[1][dotted]{%
  \stepcounter{SplCounter}%
  \setlength{\yplace}{\dimexpr\textheight/2-\pagetotal-1.5\baselineskip\relax}%
  \tikzmark{Spl\theSplCounter}%
  \par
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
  \draw[#1] ([yshift=\yplace,xshift=-\paperwidth/2]current page.center)--([yshift=\yplace,xshift=\paperwidth/2]current page.east);%
  \end{tikzpicture}\par
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]\mySplitter

\lipsum[3]\mySplitter[dashdotted,red,ultra thick]

\lipsum[4]\mySplitter[-,green!34!brown,thick]
Could just write the text here without empty lines... A
new paragraph will start even if I don't want to...

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Because of the overlay usage you have to compile twice ...