# Horizontal line spanning the page with asymmetric margins

Tags: rules

I wish to draw a horizontal line spanning the entire page. Previously I've been using the method in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19582/194994), but I just found that it doesn't work properly on pages with asymmetric margins (say `2in` on the left and `1in` on the right, or vice versa).

I did come up with a method that works in all usual cases, but it is a little bit ugly:

```
\noindent\hspace*{-\paperwidth}\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{4\paperwidth}{2pt}}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Below is a MWE to play with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2in,right=1in]{geometry}
% \usepackage[left=1in,right=2in]{geometry}
% \usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{2pt}}
% \noindent\hspace*{-\paperwidth}\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{4\paperwidth}{2pt}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: have a look at the answer below --from --https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410689/i-need-to-draw-a-dotted-line-to-divide-a-page-ignoring-the-margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution use TikZ.  Remember to run it twice.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \coordinate (baseline) at (0,{0.5\ht\strutbox-0.5\dp\strutbox});
  \draw (current page.west |- baseline) -- (current page.east |- baseline);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. May I ask what does `{0.5\ht\strutbox-0.5\dp\strutbox}` stand for?

Comment: That is the distance from the baseline to the center of a \strut.  If you want the baseline, just use (0,0).

Comment: I like this answer, since TikZ brings a lot features such as stylish dashed lines. It is a pity that it requires a second run to correctly locate the line.

Comment: [remember picture] stores the local origin in the aux file (which is the only way to get absolute locations).  The second run is needed to read this value.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=2in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\dividepage}{%
        \par\noindent
        \makebox[\linewidth]{\raisebox{.2\baselineskip}{\makebox[2\paperwidth]{\hrulefill}}}%
        \par
    }

        \lipsum[1]
        
        \dividepage
        
        \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool, how can I change the thickness of this `\hrulefill`?

Comment: i have no idea --you may like to ask a new question to attract a larger audience

Comment: According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65734/194994), one may replace the `\hrulefill` by `\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height ...\hfill\kern\z@` to allow changing its thickness.